# with all good wishes

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I wonder whether it is correct to write “with all good wishes of health and happiness”? Is it ok to use the preposition “of” here. 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I would use "for" instead.  Please take the "tour" by clicking on the "?" on the upper right of your screen.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with *of*. Although different people might phrase it differently.

Comment: I would avoid prepositions altogether and just say, "I wish you health and happiness."

Answer (score 1):

The language is a little florid, and it would be more natural to use ***for*** rather than ***of***, but it's otherwise fine.

When people *wish*, and the aim of that wish is a noun, the usual phrasing is that they ***wish for*** that thing. If they are wishing with the aim of something being done, a verb phrase, it's usually **wish that** ("I wish that I were ten feet tall", or "I wish that you had a heart"), though you can also omit any preposition in that case ("I wish you would just stop fighting").

However, "wish of" is also attested, often for abstract nouns (like *peace* or *love*, or *happiness*). "Wish for" is significantly more typical, though. To see summary data on this, and you can try playing with other phrases, see [this Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wish%20for%20love%2Cwish%20of%20love%2Cwish%20for%20peace%2Cwish%20of%20peace%2Cwish%20for%20happiness%2C%20wish%20of%20happiness&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwish%20for%20love%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwish%20of%20love%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwish%20for%20peace%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwish%20of%20peace%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwish%20for%20happiness%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwish%20of%20happiness%3B%2Cc0).